# Bootstrap accordion, changing "+" to "-" on collapse using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I am currently trying to displaying the 'minus (hyphen)' sign once user clicks the button. So far, the codes that I'd try, is not working. Can you point out where is the mistakes?

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
href="#collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-
controls="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="collapsed text15">

   <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    Slot Name

</a>
```

I try this code but it's not working.

```
 jQuery('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   jQuery(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
});

jQuery('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   jQuery(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

Comment: is the code at the bottom of the page? or wrapped in a ready function? (i.e. `$(function(){...});` )

Comment: You have used **jQuery('#accordion')** but there is not assigned **id="accordion"** with anchor tag.

Comment: i wrapped it using [  jQuery(function() {.....});  ] and also just like the codes shown above. But still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".glyphicon").removeClass` selects all icons, that's probably not what you want. Use `$(e.target).prev().find("i")` to get to the icon in stead. Check this working demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {  
    if ($(this).is(e.target)) {
      snippet.log("show "+this.id)
    }
    $(e.target).prev().find("i").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
  })
  $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) { 
    if ($(this).is(e.target)) {
      snippet.log("hide "+this.id)
    }
    $(e.target).prev().find("i").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"><i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"><i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this part ... $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) should the .collapse be .collapsed or just .collapse?

Comment: @user7560422, it's "collapse" --> [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can add  `class="showhide"` and use following script for this

```
$(document).on('click', '.showhide', function (event) {
    var icon = $(this).find('i:first');
    icon.toggleClass('glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus');
});

<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
href="#collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-
controls="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="collapsed text15 showhide">
   <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    Slot Name
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that with CSS

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
content: "\e113";
float: right;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e114";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background-color: rgba(19, 162, 176, 0.1);
  border-left: 17px solid #13a2b0;
}

.sample-accordion {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-title {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Kepler Std";
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.panel-body {
  border-left: 4px solid #13a2b0;
  padding: 28px 28px 0 28px;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 28px;
}

.sample-accordion-item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sample-accordion-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.accordion-image {
  height: 100px;
}

.accordion-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordion-item-link {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Kepler Std";
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.accordion-item-link:hover {
  color: #13a2b0;
}

.accordion-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: "\e113";
  float: right;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e114";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
  List
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="sample-accordion">
            <li class="sample-accordion-item">
              <div class="accordion-item"><a class="accordion-item-link">Item 1</a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="sample-accordion-item">
              <div class="accordion-item"><a class="accordion-item-link">Item 2</a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="sample-accordion-item">
              <div class="accordion-item"><a class="accordion-item-link">Item 3</a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="sample-accordion-item">
              <div class="accordion-item"><a class="accordion-item-link">Item 4</a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="sample-accordion-item">
              <div class="accordion-item"><a class="accordion-item-link">Item 5</a></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```